# 'Local folks' and 'local inhabitants': What are the differences between those terms?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning

My English exercise book has this multiple-choice question:

> Will local ___ get employment in the new business?
>
> ```
> a. folks
> b. civil
> c. civilian
> d. inhabitants
> ```

To me, b & c sound weird in this case, so I wonder if a or d is the correct answer. 
Although I found the original sentence [in Macmillian's dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/folk_1) using the word 'local folks', I also searched on Google and realized that the phrase 'local inhabitants' is used quite a lot in English.

Can you tell me what are the differences between those terms and which one is correct in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, per MacMillan, the word *folks* refers to *people in general*, it would be natural to qualify *folks* with *local*, because the question is asking about *folks/people who are local*.

*Inhabitants* might work better if the sentence did not contain *local*, because *inhabitants* are *local* by definition. They are not *people in general* but *people who live here*, so you are saying *local people who live here*, which is redundant and probably not as good as saying *local folks*. And oftentimes tests are looking for the best answer not the only answer.

Also *[folk](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=folk)* is a genuine Old English word, while *[inhabitant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inhabitant&allowed_in_frame=0)* entered English centuries later and is ultimately Latin. So it is conceived of as being more formal and used in more formal or even scientific contexts, while *folks* is for us common folk(s) speaking everyday non-formal English.

A better choice than *inhabitants* would have been *residents*.

You are right to say *civil* and *civilian* sound weird  and they probably do because they are an adjective and a singular noun, while the sentence requires a plural noun.

Finally, many multiple choice questions are poorly written and actually do give more than one answer that is correct. Sometimes all of the choices are correct. *Inhabitants* is not flat out wrong here. I'm just trying to think of reasons I would use *folks* instead.